# Java script geet time and value from radiobutton

Tags: javascript, html

I need js which get time from timer next read value from radiobutton and save time and value in msgbox like that "00:08:30:12,1,4". I have a timer and a piece of js code, but Idk what to do now. Can anybody help me ?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Stopwatch</title>
<script language="javascript">

var base = 60;

var clocktimer,dateObj,dh,dm,ds,ms;
var readout='';
var h=1;
var m=1;
var tm=1;
var s=0;
var ts=0;
var ms=0;
var show=true;
var init=0;
var m0=0;
var mPLUS=new Array(
    'm0',
    'm1',
    'm2',
    'm3',
    'm4',
    'm5',
    'm6',
    'm7',
    'm8',
    'm9'
    );
var ii=0;

function clearALL() {
    clearTimeout(clocktimer);
    h=1;m=1;tm=1;s=0;ts=0;ms=0;
    init=0;show=true;
    readout='00:00:00.00';
    document.clockform.clock.value=readout;
    var CF = document.clockform;
    for (ij=0;ij<=9;ij++) { CF[mPLUS[ij]].value = ''; }
    ii = 0;
    }

function addMEM() {
if (init>0) {
        var CF = document.clockform;
        CF[mPLUS[ii]].value = readout;
        if (ii==9) { ii = 0; } else { ii++; }
        }
}   


function startTIME() {

var cdateObj = new Date();
var t = (cdateObj.getTime() - dateObj.getTime())-(s*1000);

if (t>999) { s++; }

if (s>=(m*base)) {
    ts=0;
    m++;
    } else {
    ts=parseInt((ms/100)+s);
    if(ts>=base) { ts=ts-((m-1)*base); }
    }

if (m>(h*base)) {
    tm=1;
    h++;
    } else {
    tm=parseInt((ms/100)+m);
    if(tm>=base) { tm=tm-((h-1)*base); }
    }

ms = Math.round(t/10);
if (ms>99) {ms=0;}
if (ms==0) {ms='00';}
if (ms>0&&ms<=9) { ms = '0'+ms; }

if (ts>0) { ds = ts; if (ts<10) { ds = '0'+ts; }} else { ds = '00'; }
dm=tm-1;
if (dm>0) { if (dm<10) { dm = '0'+dm; }} else { dm = '00'; }
dh=h-1;
if (dh>0) { if (dh<10) { dh = '0'+dh; }} else { dh = '00'; }

readout = dh + ':' + dm + ':' + ds + '.' + ms;
if (show==true) { document.clockform.clock.value = readout; }

clocktimer = setTimeout("startTIME()",1);
}

function findTIME() {
if (init==0) {
    dateObj = new Date();
    startTIME();
    init=1;
    } 

}
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor=tan>
<form name=clockform>
<table bgcolor=cornsilk align=center cellpadding=5 border=1 bordercolor=burlywood><tr><td>
<table cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0 border=0 align=center>
<tr>
<td bgcolor=wheat><input name=clock value="00:00:00.00" style="text-align:center; width:174px; height:35px; font-size:24; font-weight:bold"></td>
<td valign=top bgcolor=wheat><input name=clearer type=button value="Reset" onclick="clearALL()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2 bgcolor=wheat>
<input name=starter type=button value="Start" style="width:97px; font-weight:bold" onclick="findTIME()">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<input name=marker type=button value="Mark" style="width:84px" onclick="addMEM()"><br><font style="font-size:9pt">&nbsp;</font></td>
</tr>

</table>
<table cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0 border=0 align=left>
<div align="left"><br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="1"> 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="2"> 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="3"> 3<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="4"> 4<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="5"> 5<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="6"> 6<br>
</div>
<div align="right"><br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="1"> 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="2"> 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="3"> 3<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="4"> 4<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="5"> 5<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="6"> 6<br>
</div>
</table>
<table cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0 border=0 align=center style="width:97px; font-weight:bold">
<textarea name="m0"  style="text-align:left; width:83px cols="40" rows="5" readonly="readonly">
</textarea>
</form>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in "00:08:30:12,1,4" do u mean 1,4 are values from the radio boxes?

Comment: off-topic, but important: your page layout is using some very nasty table structures. You also haven't got a doctype. And there are a few other out-of-date aspects to your style. You need to update your coding techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code for you

I also fixed the reset and some of the table issues

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Stopwatch</title>
<script language="javascript">

var base = 60;

var clocktimer,dateObj,dh,dm,ds,ms;
var readout='';
var h=1;
var m=1;
var tm=1;
var s=0;
var ts=0;
var ms=0;
var show=true;
var init=0;
var m0=0;
var mPLUS=['m0','m1','m2','m3','m4','m5','m6','m7','m8','m9'];
var ii=0;

function clearALL() {
    clearTimeout(clocktimer);
    h=1;m=1;tm=1;s=0;ts=0;ms=0;
    init=0;show=true;
    readout='00:00:00.00';
    document.clockform.clock.value=readout;
    var CF = document.clockform;
    for (ij=0;ij<mPLUS.length;ij++) { if (CF[mPLUS[ij]]) CF[mPLUS[ij]].value = ''; }
    ii = 0;
    }

function addMEM() {
if (init>0) {
        var CF = document.clockform;
        CF[mPLUS[ii]].value = readout;
        if (ii==9) { ii = 0; } else { ii++; }
        }
}   


function startTIME() {

var cdateObj = new Date();
var t = (cdateObj.getTime() - dateObj.getTime())-(s*1000);

if (t>999) { s++; }

if (s>=(m*base)) {
    ts=0;
    m++;
    } else {
    ts=parseInt((ms/100)+s);
    if(ts>=base) { ts=ts-((m-1)*base); }
    }

if (m>(h*base)) {
    tm=1;
    h++;
    } else {
    tm=parseInt((ms/100)+m);
    if(tm>=base) { tm=tm-((h-1)*base); }
    }

ms = Math.round(t/10);
if (ms>99) {ms=0;}
if (ms==0) {ms='00';}
if (ms>0&&ms<=9) { ms = '0'+ms; }

if (ts>0) { ds = ts; if (ts<10) { ds = '0'+ts; }} else { ds = '00'; }
dm=tm-1;
if (dm>0) { if (dm<10) { dm = '0'+dm; }} else { dm = '00'; }
dh=h-1;
if (dh>0) { if (dh<10) { dh = '0'+dh; }} else { dh = '00'; }

readout = dh + ':' + dm + ':' + ds + '.' + ms;
if (show==true) { document.clockform.clock.value = readout; }

clocktimer = setTimeout("startTIME()",1);
}

function findTIME() {
if (init==0) {
    dateObj = new Date();
    startTIME();
    init=1;
    } 
}
var times = {};
window.onload=function() {
  var inpt = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i=0,n=inpt.length;i<n;i++) {
    if (inpt[i].type=="radio") inpt[i].onclick=function() {
      times[this.id]=this.form.m0.value=this.form.clock.value;
    } 
  }
}
function showTimes() {
  var text ="";
  for (var o in times) text += o+":"+times[o]+"\n"
  if (text) alert(text)
} 

</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor=tan>
<form name=clockform>
<table bgcolor=cornsilk align=center cellpadding=5 border=1 bordercolor=burlywood><tr><td>
<table cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0 border=0 align=center>
<tr>
<td bgcolor=wheat><input name=clock value="00:00:00.00" style="text-align:center; width:174px; height:35px; font-size:24; font-weight:bold"></td>
<td valign=top bgcolor=wheat><input name=clearer type=button value="Reset" onclick="clearALL()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2 bgcolor=wheat>
<input name=starter type=button value="Start" style="width:97px; font-weight:bold" onclick="findTIME()">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<input name=marker type=button value="Mark" style="width:84px" onclick="addMEM()"><br><font style="font-size:9pt">&nbsp;</font></td>
</tr>

<tr><td>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="r1.1" value="1"> 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="r1.2" value="2"> 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="r1.3" value="3"> 3<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="r1.4" value="4"> 4<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="r1.5" value="5"> 5<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="r1.6" value="6"> 6<br>
</td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="group2" id="r2.1" value="1"> 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" id="r2.2" value="2"> 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" id="r2.3" value="3"> 3<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" id="r2.4" value="4"> 4<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" id="r2.5" value="5"> 5<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" id="r2.6" value="6"> 6<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">
<textarea name="m0"  style="text-align:left; width:83px cols="40" rows="5" readonly="readonly">
</textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="showTimes()" value="show times">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```